# Wix Installer - How do I dynamically choose which files to ship in installer?

Tags: installation, wix, windows-installer

Our product has option to Connect to SQL, MySql, & Oracle.

I thought of shipping all dlls required for connectivity , irrespective of what member wants, but this is increasing the msi size . ( using ms build )

Can I have some sort of group in Wix, and runtime based on parameter it picks which dlls to ship ?
OR probably having multiple .wxs file (one for each db driver) and runtime decided which one to pick ?

Comment: Runtime describes application behavior.  Buildtime and Installtime are more applicable.  Which do you want?

Comment: @ChristopherPainter :) , right, buildtime is what I am looking for. We build installer per request , per member .

Answer (score 2):

Organize the files for your different dataproviders into different features.  Then use preprocessor statements based on variables to include or exclude features from your build.  Finally pass the variables into the WiX build for evaluation.   You should also give the different MSI's unique ProductName, ProductCode and PackageCode properties.  Probably the same UpgradeCode.   You may also need to consider checks in the installer to make sure only one variation is installed at a time unless you install to different directories and your components are fully isolated by design.

Also, if the three data providers are your only variation points then I imagine you'd only have 7 variations.  You might want to prebuild those 7 and then publish the content to your distribution channel.

[Preprocessor](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix2/preprocessor.htm)

Comment: Thanks for reply. I think only preprocessor will solve my problem. in my wxs if have list of files for oracle and then list of files for mysql. Can i not wrap the oracle files with <?if IncludeOracle=true ?> ? , IncludeOracle as environment variable... ?

Comment: Take a look at the Fragment concept and associated element relationships of Feature, FeatureRef, Component, ComponentRef, Directory and DirectoryRef.  The idea is you organize those files into a fragment wxs files and put a if around the Feature element.  If it evaluates to true the Feature is consumed and the ref chain is followed pulling all of it into your installer.